# How to make a polymorphic dataclass constructor method

Tags: python, factory

I have 3 dataclass objects say:

```
class Message1:
    def __init__(a):
       ...

class Message2:
    def __init__(d,e,f):
       ...

class Message3:
    def __init__(g,i):
       ...
```

For these 3 messages I want to make a factory type method which can return one of the three objects if it succeeds and if not it should return either the one it identified as the correct message to be created but failed at creation or it should notify the user that it could not create any of the messages. Are there any OOP patterns for this?

My initial thought was to do a:

```
def factory_method(**parameters):
    try:
        Message1(**parameters)
    except TypeError:
        try:
            Message2(**parameters)
        except:
            try:
                Message3(**parameters)
            except:
                print("Could not deduce message type")
```

My issue with this idea is that:

1. It's not a dynamically scalable solution, with each new message class I introduce I need to add a new try catch block
2. If the whole nested block structure fails, I have no feedback as to why, was the parameters correct for one of the message but wrong value, or was it plain gibberish?

I realize this might be a bit opinion based on what the best outcome is. At the same time it might be the solution is not too elegant and the simplest way is to just tell the factory_method what kind of message to initialize. Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the point that each class has a different number of arguments? In that case you can create a dict like `{1: Message1, 2: Message3, 3: Message2}` and then with `len(parameters)` you can figure out which one to call or whether to raise an error.

Comment: Just loop over the classes

Answer (score 1):

If you can't join them all in a single class and you can't point a call to a single class, i would match the arguments to the posible class. To make it work a type hint  and a "proxy" class is required. This example asumes that any of the classes wont contain a `__init__(*args, **kwargs)`, and to add a new class you just add it to `Message.msg_cls`, you can eval the global scope if you don't want to add manually each class.

```
class Message1:
    def __init__(self, a: int, alt=None, num=10):
        print('Message 1')

class Message2:
    def __init__(self, d: str, e: str, f: int):
        print('Message 2')

class Message3:
    def __init__(self, g: int, i: any):
        print('Message 3')


class Message:

    msg_cls = (
        Message1,
        Message2,
        Message3
    )

    @staticmethod
    def eq_kwargs(cls, kwargs):
        cls_kwargs = cls.__init__.__defaults__
        if cls_kwargs is None:
            if len(kwargs) > 0:
                return False
            else:
                return True
        cls_astr = cls.__init__.__code__
        kw_types = [type(t) for t in cls_kwargs]
        for k in kwargs:
            if k in cls_astr.co_varnames:
                if type(kwargs[k]) in kw_types:
                    kw_types.remove(type(kwargs[k]))
                else:
                    if type(None) in kw_types:
                        kw_types.remove(type(None))
                    else:
                        return False
            else:
                return False
        return True

    @staticmethod
    def eq_args(cls, args):
        cls_args = cls.__init__.__annotations__
        if len(cls_args) != len(args):
            return False
        for a, b in zip(args, cls_args):
            if type(a) != cls_args[b] and cls_args[b] != any:
                return False
        return True

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        for mc in Message.msg_cls:
            if Message.eq_args(mc, args):
                if Message.eq_kwargs(mc, kwargs):
                    return mc(*args, **kwargs)
        raise ValueError('Message.__new__, no match')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ms_1_a = Message(1, alt='a')
    ms_1_b = Message(2, alt='a', num=5)

    ms_2 = Message('X', 'Y', 5)

    ms_3_a = Message(1, [1, 4])
    ms_3_b = Message(2, Message(10))
```

Comment: This is a pretty cool example use I'll give it a try and see how it looks